Homey custom pair views
I created a homey app with a custom pair view. It works as expected on homey web app but when i try to add a new device from the homey app (smartphone), the custom view opens and closes right after being displayed. any help for debugging would appreciated.
ps: on https://tools.developer.homey.app pairing also works as expected
I tried web app and https://tools.developer.homey.app, only the phone application fails

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
